# How to code piecewise survival models in R (e.g. Kaplan-Meier curve with an extrapolated tail)

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I would like to ask how to create piecewise survival models in R (e.g. a Kaplan-Meier curve with an extrapolated tail (regardless of the distribution), see attached figure as an example?

For example how to create a curve where I fit the exponential distribution when the time is 200 in the example below (so that I would get a similar looking curve like in the attached figure)?

```
library(survival)
library(flexsurv)
library(dplyr)

data <- survival::lung %>% filter(time < 300)

formula <- Surv(data$time, data$status) ~1

model <- flexsurvreg(formula = formula, dist = "exp", na.action = na.exclude)

plot(model, main = "plot",
     col.obs = "black",
     col = "blue")
```

[image: Example of piecewise survival model (ref: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4934460/)]

Answer (score 0):

The model has class "flexsurvreg", so the help page for `plot.flexsurvreg` should give you the answers, as well as the `plot.survfit` function, which accepts the `...` argument. So, to get a plot similar to the one you show, the following may be a start:

```
plot(model, main = "plot",
     col.obs = "black",
     col = "blue", 
     ci=FALSE,
     conf.int=FALSE,
     las=2,  # axis tick labels always perpendicular to axes
     xlab="Time (months)",
     ylab="Percentage alive")
```

[image]

I hope you didn't want the ugly x-axis breaks or the 3 significant digits for the y-axis tick labels. By the way, the y-axis label should really be Proportion alive.